# Cleanup branch with too many little merges

Tags: git

Searching for help to clean my branch. I cut my work on too many small fixes and I have too many merges for these fixes on `master`. I would like to gather my fixes to one bigger fix branch. From this:

```
(C0)<----(C1)<----(C2)<----(C3)   master
           \      / \      /
            \(F1)/   \(F2)/

    C2, C3 - merges from small fixes
```

To this:

```
(C0)<----(C1)<------------(C4')   master
           \               /
            \(F1)<----(F2)/
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: git merge --squash should do the job. first marge all small fixes into a dev branch, ant then squash-merge into the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do what you want, but keep in mind that if other people share the `master` branch with you, and they already have the old version of the history, and they've already done more work (commits) on top of it, then you'll force them to have to re-sync their work with the new history.

Do the following:

```bash
git checkout -b new-branch F1
git cherry-pick F2
git checkout master
git reset --hard C1
git merge --no-ff new-branch

# If you need to push to a remote, you'll need to force push
# if the old history was already pushed:
git push <remote> head --force
```

Comment: Yes, that will work. You can read the [documentation for `cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html).

Answer (score 0):

If `F1` is in branch `feature-a` and `F2` in `feature-b`, the following should work:

```
git checkout feature-b
git rebase feature-a
git checkout feature-a
git merge-feature-b
```

It rebases all patches in `feature-b` on `feature-a` and afterwards does a fast forward merge to include those commits in `feature-b` branch.

Now you can delete the obsolete feature-b branch since now feature-a contains all its commits

```
git branch -d feature-b
```

Comment: Interesting. I have already used the Cupcake solution, but this looks like less hacky for beginner. Hope to check this some day.

Comment: How are you going to change the history that already exists for `master`?

Comment: Hmm. here is something missing indeed. must be reset at some point. Could it work with reset on `master` at some moment?